# vctl errors with "The virtual machine is not powered on"

Tags: macos, vmware, vmware-fusion

I am on MacBook Pro M2 2022 with macOS Ventura, using VMware Fusion.

The problem is that `vctl` can't run a container. `vctl pull` works just fine, and the container engine is started but the `vctl run -n myNginx -t -d nginx` errors with the following messages:

```
ERROR failed to stop a sandbox, err:error code:exit status 255, message:Error: The virtual machine is not powered on: /Users/user/.vctl/.r/vms/myNginx/myNginx.vmx  module=libcrx package=sandbox
ERROR failed to create container: error code:exit status 255, message:2023-07-15T09:40:35.738| ServiceImpl_Opener: PID 2378
Error: The operation was canceled
```

Is there any way to fix this?